# System objects return wrong GRANTs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-grant

I found strange bug or behaviour on our SQL Server 2008R. I am trying to give EXECUTE permissions to a role for 1 schema. However when I am looking to the system objects I see that **EXECUTE** permissions are set to the **SYSTEM_TABLE  sysallocunits**. If I give permissions to any other schema then everything goes well and the permissions are set to the schema.
I use following query

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::Sync TO [app_TSSyncService_web_svc]

select  princ.name 
,       princ.type_desc 
,       perm.permission_name 
,       perm.state_desc 
,       perm.class_desc 
,       object_name(perm.major_id) 
from    sys.database_principals princ 
left join 
        sys.database_permissions perm 
on      perm.grantee_principal_id = princ.principal_id 
WHERE princ.name = 'app_TSSyncService_web_svc'
```

I am getting following output:

```
name    type_desc   permission_name state_desc  class_desc  (No column name)
app_TSSyncService_web_svc   DATABASE_ROLE   EXECUTE GRANT   SCHEMA  sysallocunits
```

The same thing happens when I grant permissions to this schema for any other role.

**UPDATE**
Just found out that my schema has the same object_id sysallocunits any suggestions how can I rewrite query to ignore it without hardcoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you schema has a `schema_id` that happens to have the same numeric value as the `object_id` for `sysallocunits`.

You query is wrong for checking permissions for anything that isn't an object; for a schema, you'd want to join `major_id` from [`sys.database_permissions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx) to the `schema_id` in [`sys.schemas`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176011.aspx), rather than assuming that it's an `object_id` to join to `sys.objects`.

I'm not going to attempt to completely re-write your query here since I don't know what class(es) you'll want to be able to query permissions for.

Comment: Your answer is good enough for me. Do not need to re-write the query. One more question, are there any other issues with that? I mean what else except schema can cause this situation? Can I asume that if the record has major_id > 0 it is not object?